# IE8 not rendering correct MVC HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8

My company is asking me to debug a contractor's project that was done in MVC. The issue I'm struggling with is getting the HTML to render correctly with IE8. The rendered HTML is completely missing many closing tags. I am testing using a VM with IE8 installed. Below is a screenshot of the Developer Tools:

[image: IE8 Screenshot]

On Chrome the output is correct, and below is a screenshot of that code from Chrome's Developer Tools:

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Any suggestions are much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: good luck!  =) can you fire that contractor again?

Comment: Start by pasting the *actual* output (not the developer view) into http://validator.w3.org. Chances are, the markup is invalid.

Comment: IE dev tools dont show the closing tags but they are there. Right click on web page and view source and you will see them. I believe IE8 is being dropped by MS son if thats a consolation. I am pretty happy anyway

Comment: If you can give more detail on the issue i might be able to help. Its most likely the site was not developed for IE.

Comment: The DOM Explorer may not show closing tags in older versions of IE, but that doesn't mean much. It is clearly nesting elements, which means the parser is understanding relationships. What specific problem are you seeing in the actual viewport?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. The specific problem I'm having is two tables are being removed from the output only in IE8. I am unable to validate on validator.w3.org as this project is yet to be hosted, but running a localhost validator yelds many html errors. I guess I will begin cleaning those up, and hopefully it fixes my issue. @TimMedora

Comment: @KevDevMan Thank you for informing me on IE's dev tools. When you say it's most likely the site was not developed for IE, what do you mean?

Comment: @TimMedora I have cleaned up all validation errors except around 15 that are like this:  The align attribute on the td element is obsolete. Use CSS instead. I doubt this could cause the issue..

Comment: You are correct; validly-formed attributes (even if they are obsolete) probably wouldn't cause structural issues. Two other suggestions: 1) make sure you are you testing on "real" IE8 (not just by setting IE8 in the dev tools in a later version). 2) Find the minimum amount of markup needed to create the problem, and add it to your question.

Comment: @TimMedora I am using "real" IE8 as I am testing on an XP VM. I'm not even sure where I would begin to narrow down the markup, as the page uses many Partial Views as well as Ajax inserted code.